# ionic external link restarts app when pressing back button

Tags: ionic-framework, back-button

After an afternoon of searching, I still can't find a workable solution to this problem.

The problem is that I have some dynamic data retrieved from a backend api that has some urls in i.e. html anchor links. The links open fine, but when I try to go back to the app by tapping the back button, the app always restarts and hence throws me back to the login screen, which would be very annoying to the end users.

I need the back button to go back to the previous page that the user was on.

I've tried various incarnations of attributes, suggested by a whole range of forum posts, but none of them solve the problem:

```
<a href="https://someurl.com" class="content__link" target="_blank">My website</a>

<a href="#" data-link="https://someurl.com" ng-click="goTolink($event)" class="content__link">My website</a>

<a href="#" data-link="https://someurl.com" onclick="goTolink('https://someurl.com')" class="content__link">My website</a>

<a href="#" onclick="window.open('https://someurl.com', '_system', 'location=yes')" class="content__link">My website</a>
```

The goTolink function is:

```
goTolink(event): void {
    if (event.currentTarget
    &&  event.currentTarget.attributes['data-link']) {
        this.iab.create(event.currentTarget.attributes['data-link'], "_blank", "location=true");
    }
}
```

I have several console.log messages in there too, but nothing is showing in the console, so it can't be being called.

Any suggestions of how I can tap the back button and go back to the previous app page without the app restarting are very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample code. Hope it will help with your problem.

Add this in HTML file

```
<a (click)="goTolink"> Click </a>
```

and put this code in typescript after the constructor code.

```
goTolink() {
  window.open('https://someurl.com', '_target')//sample 1
  window.open('https://someurl.com', '_blank')//sample 2
}
```

Comment: I've tried adding the click to the url in the data on the backend, but it doesn't get rendered to the page on the app, even though the app receives it in the data, so the goto method isn't ever called. How would I get the goto method to be called?  The link I'm testing in the browser is: <a href="https://example.com" target="_system" (click)="goToLink('https://example.com')">My website</a>. I've also tried <a href="#" target="_system" (click)="goToLink('https://example.com')">My website</a>, but that just opens a browser tab that goes to localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one if it will fit in your coding.

HTML file:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="goToLink('www.example.com')">My website</a>
```

Typescript file:

```
goTolink(link) {
   window.open(link, '_blank')
}
```

Hoping this one will help.